# change order of list that uses pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I have a paginated list that displays 10 items to a page, but I want to give the option for someone to change the order of the list, for example, by gender or age.

The pagination works, and in terms of sorting the list, so far I have:

```
$orderby = ($_GET['orderby'] == 'gender')? $_GET['orderby'] : 'age';

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY $orderby"))
```

With 2 basic links: gender | age

```
echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?orderby=gender'>gender</a> | <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?orderby=age'>age</a>";
```

When I click one of the links, it changes the order of the list as required, but when I go to another page of the pagination, it does not work.

Can someone please let me know of the best way to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: I just use a SESSION variable for my order by.  If it is NULL, it gets assigned a default value.  Users can also "kill" their current ordering to get back to the default.  Etc.

Comment: please provide your pagination code

Answer (score 0):

Try my function `genPagnation()`, please refer my code below:

```
<?

$totalPage = 23;
$currentPage = isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] >= 1 ? (int)$_GET['p'] : 1;
$params = array();
$devices = array();

if( isset($_POST['order']) || isset($_GET['order']) ){
    $params['order'] = isset($_POST['order']) ? $_POST['order'] : $_GET['order'];
}

if( isset($_POST['device']) || isset($_GET['device']) ){
    $params['device'] = isset($_POST['device']) ? $_POST['device'] : $_GET['device'];
    $devices = $params['device'];
}

for( $i = 1; $i <= $totalPage; $i++ ){
    if( $i == $currentPage )
        print("&nbsp;<b><u>{$i}</u></b>&nbsp;");
    else
        print("&nbsp;<a href='" . genPagnation($i, $params) . "'>{$i}</a>&nbsp;");
}
print("<p><hr /></p>\n\n");


function genPagnation($p, $param = array(), $pname = null, $pvalue = null){
    $param['p'] = $p;
    if( !empty($pname) && !empty($pvalue) )
        $param[ $pname ] = $pvalue;

    $query = http_build_query($param);
    $query = preg_replace('/%5B[0-9]+%5D/', '%5B%5D', $query);
    return '?' . $query;
}

?>

<p>
    Order By: 
    <a href='<?=genPagnation($currentPage, $params, "order", "male")?>'>Male</a> | 
    <a href='<?=genPagnation($currentPage, $params, "order", "female")?>'>Female</a>
</p>

<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <p>
        Filtering:
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="device[]" value="iphone"  <? if( !empty($devices) && in_array('iphone', $devices) ){  echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />iPhone</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="device[]" value="ipad"    <? if( !empty($devices) && in_array('ipad', $devices) ){    echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />iPad</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="device[]" value="ipod"    <? if( !empty($devices) && in_array('ipod', $devices) ){    echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />iPod</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="device[]" value="android" <? if( !empty($devices) && in_array('android', $devices) ){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />Android</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        Ordering:
        <label><input type="radio" name="order" value="male"   <? if( isset($_REQUEST['order']) && $_REQUEST['order'] == 'male'){   echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />Male</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="order" value="female" <? if( isset($_REQUEST['order']) && $_REQUEST['order'] == 'female'){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />Female</label>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="search"></p>
</form>
```